# Handle New Categories for both training and test set

Tags: one-hot-encoding, label-encoding

I worked on a classification problem for the Kaggle Competition, and I found there are 3 categorical columns, but I noticed that the service column in the train data has 66 categories, and in the test data it has 64 categories only as shown on the screen.
How could I handle the problem of encoding?
[categories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJSMs.png)

I made fit then transform for test data, was that right?
[label encoding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/37sew.png)

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please do not provide code as screenshots. Instead, please copy and paste the code in the question and format it properly. Thanks!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.